# In PostgreSQL, how to store multiple ids (related to a single value) in the same row?

Tags: postgresql

I've installed PostgreSQL 15, and I'm currently working with no other first/third-party addons or tools.

Here you have a simple example of what I'm trying to achieve.

I have a table "Category", populated like this:

| id(PK) | Description |
| --- | --- |
| C1 | Category 1 |
| C2 | Category 2 |
| C3 | Category 3 |
| C4 | Category 4 |

I need to populate a new table "Product Count" where each category is bound to the count of sell products in a given year. Unluckily, for some categories, I only have the summation for those categories.

Data is arranged in an Excel file shaped like the following:

| year | category | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | C1 | 150 |
| 2020 | C2, C3 | 100 |
| 2020 | C4 | 400 |
| 2021 | C1 | 200 |
| 2021 | C2, C3, C4 | 350 |

What I need is a way to conveniently store this data in a table whose PK is ( year, category_id(s) ). But I don't know exactly how to design the solution.

The actual problem is that since the count value is aggregated, I need to aggregate categories, that I want to be part of my primary key.

What I thought by far is to have an intermediate table (that can be called "Category Group") that takes into account of the category aggregation:

| group_id | category_id |
| --- | --- |
| G1 | C1 |
|  |  |
| G2 | C2 |
| G2 | C3 |
|  |  |
| G3 | C4 |
|  |  |
| G4 | C2 |
| G4 | C3 |
| G4 | C4 |

So that the Product Count table could leverage the category group to tackle the problem.
But in this way it seems a bit messy in my opinion, and moreover I lose the direct connection between categories and product count.

Is there a smarter way to design it? Can you help me?
Thank you so much!

Comment: Why not use a normalized data structure?

Comment: Are you sure you want to create a new and most likely even bigger problem? You don't want, or need, to store multiple values in a single column. Normalization is key, key to success.

Comment: You convinced me, normalization is the way. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no smarter approach. It's a well-established practice both in relational algebra and in relational databases to create a separate table in order to store many-to-many links. So, you have a(a_id, ...), b(b_id, ...), a_b(a_b_id, a_id, b_id, ...) tables to put it roughly.

This way it may seem to be messy at the first sight, but as you get more experience, it will become very clear that this separation is extremely important. Some reasons:

1. If you have multiple values of the same kind inside a single field, you violate 1NF (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) and you will have a lot of difficulties

- when you want to search for a record having an id (your ids are mixed up in a single field)
- when you update the field (you will always need to parse, change and parse back the value)
- when you remove one id that's being referenced in this composite field

2. You can reach to inconsistencies and redundancies by mixing up multiple values into a single field. When that id changes for some reason, you will always need to update all records referencing that id (see the difficulties regarding the update)
3. You will possibly waste space if both references are stored in the records of both tables